# How to merge two JSON objects in R by keeping both json structure

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have two separate objects in R which have a JSON format and I'm trying to convert into a single R objects with two JSON objects in it's structure

---

**this is my code..**

```
  studies <- get_studies(efo_trait = 'triple-negative breast cancer')
  study <- studies@studies
  publication <- studies@publications
  paste("studies", study, "publication", publication)
```

**this is what i am getting in json**

```
[
"studies c(\"GCST002305\", \"GCST010100\") publication c(\"GCST002305\", \"GCST010100\")",
"studies c(\"Breast cancer (estrogen-receptor negative, progesterone-receptor negative, and human epidermal growth factor-receptor negative)\", \"Breast cancer (estrogen-receptor negative, progesterone-receptor negative, and human epidermal growth factor-receptor negative)\") publication c(24325915, 32424353)",
"studies c(\"1,529 European ancestry cases, 3,399 European ancestry controls\", \"8,602 European ancestry triple negative cases, 9,414 European ancestry BRCA1 mutation carrier cases, 100,971 European ancestry controls\") publication c(16048, 18399)",
"studies c(\"2,148 European ancestry cases, 1,309 European ancestry controls\", NA) publication c(\"Carcinogenesis\", \"Nat Genet\")",
"studies c(FALSE, FALSE) publication c(\"Genome-wide association study identifies 25 known breast cancer susceptibility loci as risk factors for triple-negative breast cancer.\", \"Genome-wide association study identifies 32 novel breast cancer susceptibility loci from overall and subtype-specific analyses.\")",
"studies c(FALSE, FALSE) publication c(\"Purrington KS\", \"Zhang H\")",
"studies c(NA, 9700000) publication c(\"0000-0002-5710-1692\", NA)",
"studies c(NA, \"~\") publication c(\"GCST002305\", \"GCST010100\")",
"studies c(TRUE, TRUE) publication c(24325915, 32424353)",
"studies c(FALSE, FALSE) publication c(16048, 18399)",
"studies c(NA, NA) publication c(\"Carcinogenesis\", \"Nat Genet\")",
"studies c(FALSE, FALSE) publication c(\"Genome-wide association study identifies 25 known breast cancer susceptibility loci as risk factors for triple-negative breast cancer.\", \"Genome-wide association study identifies 32 novel breast cancer susceptibility loci from overall and subtype-specific analyses.\")",
"studies c(FALSE, TRUE) publication c(\"Purrington KS\", \"Zhang H\")"]
```

**but want this type of data...**

```
[
studies: {
    "study_id": "GCST002305",
    "pubmed_id": 24325915,
    "publication_date": "2013-12-09",
    "publication": "Carcinogenesis",
    "title": "Genome-wide association study identifies 25 known breast cancer susceptibility loci as risk factors for triple-negative breast cancer.",
    "author_fullname": "Purrington KS",
    "author_orcid": "0000-0002-5710-1692"
}
publication: {
    "study_id": "GCST010100",
    "pubmed_id": 32424353,
    "publication_date": "2020-05-17",
    "publication": "Nat Genet",
    "title": "Genome-wide association study identifies 32 novel breast cancer susceptibility loci from overall and subtype-specific analyses.",
    "author_fullname": "Zhang H"
}
```

]

Please Help me

Comment: paste() is a vectorized function so it's trying to read the first element from each and paste them together,  the second from each, etc.  You are wanting to treat your original objects as though they are each a single string so you need to convert them to that ... or possible use the `cat()` function.

Comment: how do i use cat()

Comment: can you please share the output of `dput(studies)` ?

Comment: Read ?cat.  There are other options also.